# How to change values in a given column based on a condition and put those new values in a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe called trade_lanes that shows an output below:

| Departure Country | Arrival Country |
| --- | --- |
| Malaysia | Poland |
| Germany | USA |
| Germany | Cameroon |
| Argentina | Vietnam |
| Algeria | Slovakia |
| China | Vietnam |
| Denmark | Singapore |

What I would like to do is create 2 new columns depending on the country: "Departure Region" and "Arrival Region" in the dataframe trade_lanes such that it looks like this as the output:

| Departure Region | Departure Country | Arrival Region | Arrival Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APAC | Malaysia | NECE | Poland |
| NECE | Germany | AMERICAS | USA |
| NECE | Germany | WEMEA | Cameroon |
| AMERICAS | Argentina | APAC | Viet Nam |
| WEMEA | Algeria | NECE | Slovakia |
| APAC | China | APAC | Vietnam |
| NECE | Denmark | APAC | Japan |
| Others | Tonga | APAC | Indonesia |

I have been working around for loops to go about this but I think I'm getting the flow processes wrong and because there's a condition where a country is tagged to region, it makes it even more complicated. Also note that, I believe I need to use a For-if-elif-else loop because there are countries in which I would label them as "Others".

I was thinking of duplicating "Departure Country" and "Arrival Country" columns and then replace it manually but I am pretty sure there's an easier way to do it using for loop.

This was what I attempted:

```
for elements in range(len(trade_lane)):
    
    apac = {"AUSTRALIA": "APAC", "BANGLADESH": "APAC", 
                  "CHINA": "APAC", "HONG KONG": "APAC",
                  "INDIA": "APAC", "INDONESIA": "APAC",
                  "JAPAN": "APAC", "MALAYSIA": "APAC",
                  "MALAYSIA": "APAC", "NEW ZEALAND": "APAC",
                     "SINGAPORE": "APAC", "KOREA": "APAC",
                    "TAIWAN": "APAC", "THAILAND": "APAC", "VIET NAM": "APAC"}

    nece = {"BELGIUM": "NECE", "CZECH REPUBLIC": "NECE",
                  "DENMARK": "NECE", "GERMANY": "NECE", "HUNGARY": "NECE",
                  "LUXEMBOURG": "NECE", "NETHERLANDS": "NECE",
                  "NORWAY": "NECE", "POLAND": "NECE", "ROMANIA": "NECE",
                  "SLOVAKIA": "NECE", "SWEDEN": "NECE", "TURKEY": "NECE"}
    
    wemea = {"ALGERIA": "WEMEA", "BAHRAIN": "WEMEA", 
                   "CAMEROON": "WEMEA", "CHAD": "WEMEA", "FRANCE": "WEMEA",
                   "GREECE": "WEMEA", "IRISH REPUBLIC": "WEMEA",
                   "ITALY": "WEMEA", "MOROCCO": "WEMEA",
                   "PORTUGAL": "WEMEA", "QATAR": "WEMEA",
                   "SAUDI ARABIA": "WEMEA", "SOUTH AFRICA": "WEMEA",
                   "SPAIN": "WEMEA", "TUNISIA": "WEMEA", "UGANDA": "WEMEA",
                   "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES": "WEMEA", "UNITED KINDGOM":"WEMEA"}
    
    americas = {"ARGENTINA": "AMERICAS", "BRAZIL": "AMERICAS",
                      "CANADA": "AMERICAS", "CHILE": "AMERICAS",
                      "COLOMBIA": "AMERICAS", "MEXICO": "AMERICAS",
                      "PERU": "AMERICAS", "UNITED STATES": "AMERICAS"}
    
    for x,y in apac.items():
        trade_lane["Departure Region"].values = trade_lane["Departure Country"].values[elements].replace(x,y)
        
trade_lane
```

However I get a KeyError: 'Departure Region'

Comment: Use a dictionary of country -> region, and `map`

Comment: @mozway could you show me how to go about doing this? I updated my question with a code I attempted to use.